# typescript how to copy object without references

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one object

```
item = { selectedItems: [] };
```

I did:

```
item1 = { ...item };
item2 = Object.assign({}, item);
item3 = Object.create(item);
```

but when I change `selectedItems` for `item1` they are changed for all items. It's angular project
What's wrong? Or what's right way?
Or it's browser cache? I can't understand

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a deep copy, example:

```
let newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your problem is other. The way that you are using to clone the objects is a way that return objects without references to the original object. For more information can see the next article: [https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-shallow-clone-objects/#:~:text=1.-,Cloning%20using%20object%20spread,the%20shallow%20copy%20of%20object%20](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-shallow-clone-objects/#:%7E:text=1.-,Cloning%20using%20object%20spread,the%20shallow%20copy%20of%20object%20).

PD: maybe you have a logic in your app that when you change selected items update the others vars.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an easy function to use next time you run into this problem.

```js
const changeMe: unknown[] = clone(dontChangeMe)

// ...

function clone<T>(obj: T): T {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```